# How to create a list of data frames as a result of subsetting an old one based on some conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following data frame:

```
    T   a  b  c
1   1   0  0  0
2   2   1  0  0
3   5   1  0  0
4   6   1  0  0
5   7   0  1  0
6   9   0  1  0
7   10  0  0  1
8   12  0  0  0
9   14  0  0  0
10  15  1  0  0
11  16  1  0  0
12  17  0  1  0
13  18  0  0  1
```

I want to subset this data frame and create a list of data frames. Each data frame has to be populated with the rows (of the old one) that there is a sequence of successively "1" in a column, then in b column and last in c column. The expected result (for this data frame) would be a list of 2 data frames:

```
data frame 1:
             T   a  b  c                          
         1   2   1  0  0                         
         2   5   1  0  0
         3   6   1  0  0
         4   7   0  1  0
         5   9   0  1  0
         6   10  0  0  1 
and data frame 2:
             T   a  b  c
         1   15  1  0  0
         2   16  1  0  0
         3   17  0  1  0
         4   18  0  0  1
```

Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not clear about the logic.  Suppose if 'c' have  1 at the same row as 'b', then how do you split

Comment: What have you tried? A simple solution could be, e.g., a looped `if...else`.

Comment: @akrun there will not be such a case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the expected output

```
i1 <- do.call(pmax, df1[-1])
grp <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(i1 ==1), {values <- seq_along(values)}))
split(df1[i1==1,], grp[i1==1])
#$`2`
#   T a b c
#2  2 1 0 0
#3  5 1 0 0
#4  6 1 0 0
#5  7 0 1 0
#6  9 0 1 0
#7 10 0 0 1

#$`4`
#    T a b c
#10 15 1 0 0
#11 16 1 0 0
#12 17 0 1 0
#13 18 0 0 1
```